# javascript, how to validate date range in textbox format?

Tags: javascript, java

I am working on specific framework and built in datebox doesn't have an option to select hour:min:sec. So I used Textbox to create that format for search engine and everything works fine. My only concern is that, this pulls too much data if I don't put limitation on this new date range from DATE1 to DATE2. How do I put 1 month limitation before it actually sends script to database?

```
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);

    var DATE1 = new TextBox({
            applyTo: 'DATE1',
            defaultValue: today.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
            "-" + ("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2) +" " + "00:00:00",
            width: 150
        });

        var DATE2 = new TextBox({
            applyTo: 'DATE2',
            defaultValue: new Date().getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
            "-" + ("0" + new Date().getDate()).slice(-2) +" " + "00:00:00",
            width: 150
        });


    btnSearch.on('click', function(){             
                 var datea = DATE1.getValue() ? DATE1.getValue() : "";
                 var dateb = DATE2.getValue() ? DATE2.getValue() : "";
    }
```

obviously.. something like if((dateb-datea) > 31) wouldn't work.
Help. :(

Comment: Some clarifications:

- The user is typing these date strings into the text boxes? Y/N

- Why are you defining `new Date()` multiple times in the definition of `DATE2` instead of defining it once beforehand?

- Your ultimate question is, given these two dates, how do you ensure that the dates are no more than a month apart? Y/N

Comment: yes. Date1 textbox will display value as 2020-03-21 00:00:00 and Date2 textbox will display value as 2020-03-22 00:00:00 as default since it gets today's date. User will modify those data as needed but I want to put limitation on search so user can't select range bigger than 1 month period.

Comment: One further clarification. What precisely do you mean by "a month apart"? Do you mean 'in an earlier month with a number day before today's number day, or in a later month with a number day after today's number day'? Or do you mean 'no more than 31 days apart'? I'm asking because I want to be sure about the constraints that you're under.

Comment: no more than a month apart. so if Date2 is selected as 2020-03-22 00:00:00 and Date1 is selected before 2020-02-22 00:00:00, search engine should just return warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you absolutely can subtract date objects in JS. The only problem is that the result comes out as number of milliseconds.

```
new Date('2020-03-15') - new Date('2020-03-10')
=> 432000000 
432000000 / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
=> 5
```

## EDIT:

Since  the actual data values from the text boxes into objects

If a fixed day-number distance were acceptable for this use case, then simply doing subtraction (with the appropriate scaling factor) would be sufficient.

However, since what you want is to check that if (for example)
today's date is 2020-03-22 and the next date is no later than 2020-04-22, then you'll need to actually do logic on the month and day values for each date.

e.g.

```
if (!(dateb.getMonth() > datea.getMonth() && dateb.getDate() > datea.getDate())) {
// ... 
}
```

## EDIT:

DATE1.getValue() is returning the value of the textbox as a string, so you'll want to convert that string into some kind of data object in order to make it easier to do logical tests. The Date class can accept time as part of the input string for its constructor, but the string needs to be in one of the formats the class recognizes (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`, where 'T' is the letter T and 'Z' stands in for the time zone - see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp). You'll need to finesse the strings a little bit, but that doesn't seem too complex. Quasi-pseudocode example below.

```
btnSearch.on('click', function(){             
  if (DATE1.getValue() && DATE2.getValue()) { // Ensure that both values exist.
    var firstDateObject = new Date(
      DATE1.getValue().split(' ').join('T') + <timezone stuff>
    );
    var secondDateObject = new Date(
      DATE2.getValue().split(' ').join('T') + <timezone stuff>
    );
    // Do some logic...
  }
}
```

Comment: the thing is, calculating DATE1 - DATE2 works if it was simple button click calculation but btn.Search grabs date value from those text box as string value and using it as parameter for SQL query. When I put something like if(datea - dateb), it won't work nor those dateb.getMonth etc as they are no longer in date format but simple string at that point.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. Are you saying that the issue is that when the click event happens, btnSearch (which I presume comes from the framework you're using) grabs the data from the TextBox instances, it pulls it in as a String, and that consequently you can't perform logical tests on it? I don't think that's a problem - those strings should be able to be passed in as parameters to new Date instances.

Comment: found my answer. date.parse solved the issue. thank you for your help though